# redeployment of ear file on application server undergoes server restart or not

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, server

I have an application server and deploy an ear file. If I do some changes on JSP, it automatically takes the changes and I see some activity on the console (I am using eclipse) and the changes are reflected. 
My question is, when I do the above change, app server is listening to the changes and doing the redeployment. During this process the server is stopped and started again by the server ?

I read that when application is redeployed multiple times, it converts a small leakage into a big leakage so it looks like it is not undergoing stop/start.

Answer (score 0):

server simply redeploys your ear, and does not restart itself.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you redeploy any ear it just undeploy that earand again deployed that ear and its dependent ears.so during this server is not restarted but its called hotdeployment which can be restrict using server configuration.Revert back to me in case of concern.

Comment: Thanks Vishrut. I was saying about automatic deployment by the app server not by me. In these cases if the server is not restarted, it would lead to memory leaks

Comment: yes definitely it cause the memory leaks so just try to restrict the redeployment in app server as it is not recommended.